These stereocilia become progressively longer on the side of the hair cell away from the modiolus
Can someone paraphrase this for me? Does it mean the largest cilia is the nearest to the modiolus or it means the largest cilia is the farthest from the modiolus?

Away from is the clue. The longest cilia are those farthest from the modiolus.
